# Database records not placing exactly continiously

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code, My primary in my database is counter.

```
<input class="textbox1" tabIndex="8" maxLength="49" size="30" name="n_counter" value='
<?php
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM procurement WHERE counter != ' '");
   while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
      $value = $row['counter'];
   }
   $i = "0";
   while ( $i <= $value ) {
      $i++;
   }
   $value2 = strlen( $i );
   if ( $value2 == 1 ) {
      echo "00000" . $i;
   } else if ( $value2 == 2 ) {
      echo "0000" . $i;
   } else if ( $value2 == 3 ) {
      echo "000" . $i;
   } else if ( $value2 == 4) {
      echo "00" . $i;
   } else if ( $value2 == 5 ) {
      echo "0" . $i;
   } else {
      echo $i;
   }
?>'>
```

The looping statement works perfectly, but the problem occurs after I delete records from database.

[image]

When I deleted 000001 records and add another records, that records goes next to 000000, what I want is 000010 should be placed next to 000009. In my other project that works fine. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Every thing is OK

just update this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM procurement WHERE counter != ' ' ORDER BY counter ASC");
```

It is strongly **Recomended** that You should use **`mysqli`** instead of `mysql`.

Yo'll have to update `connection` and then `Query execution` too.

```
$connection = ($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"] = mysqli_connect( "db_server",  "db_user",  "db_password","database" )) or die( ((is_object($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"])) ? mysqli_error($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false)) ) ;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM procurement WHERE counter != ' ' ORDER BY counter ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"],  $sql ) or die( ((is_object($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"])) ? mysqli_error($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false)) ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "ORDER BY counter ASC" in your sql query.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM procurement WHERE counter != ' ' ORDER BY counter ASC");
```